# How to auto answer an incoming Skype call?

Tags: python, skype

Is it possible to auto answer to an incoming Skype call from specific Number or contact?

I Think this should work with a Python script using Skype4py but as I am not a programmer I don't have an idea how to do this.

Anybody has any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your skype is online, i.e. that you have logged in and there are no network problems, you can do the following:

1. In the skype list of phone numbers there is a buttom at the
   bottom of the skype window which gives you access to settings. Click
   on that, and the "options" menu pops up.
2. Go to notifications,and select "incoming call ringing". Now select "Advanced View".
3. At the bottom of the "advanced view" is an option to "Execute the
   following script", in which you enter full the filepath of your
   script.
4. Press apply.

## The script

```
global _proc
global use_growl
 
tell application "System Events" to set _proc to name of processes as list
if _proc contains "GrowlHelperApp" then
    set use_growl to true
    my growlRegister()
else
    set use_growl to false
end if
 
if _proc contains "Skype" then
    tell application "Skype"
        set calls to send command "SEARCH ACTIVECALLS" script name "AnsweringScript"
        set callID to last word of calls
        if callID is not "CALLS" then
            set status to send command "GET CALL " & callID & " STATUS" script name "AnsweringScript"
            if last word of status is "RINGING" then
                send command "ALTER CALL " & callID & " ANSWER" script name "AnsweringScript"
                my growlNotify("SkypeAnswer", "Answering call")
                return
            else
                send command "ALTER CALL " & callID & " HANGUP" script name "AnsweringScript"
                my growlNotify("SkypeAnswer", "Hanging up")
            end if
        else
            my growlNotify("SkypeAnswer", "No call found to answer or hang up")
        end if
    end tell
else
    my growlNotify("SkypeAnswer", "Skype not detected")
end if
 
using terms from application "GrowlHelperApp"
    on growlRegister()
        tell application "GrowlHelperApp"
            register as application "SkypeAnswer" all notifications {"Alert"} default notifications {"Alert"} icon of application "Skype.app"
        end tell
    end growlRegister
 
    on growlNotify(grrTitle, grrDescription)
        if use_growl is true then
            tell application "GrowlHelperApp"
                notify with name "Alert" title grrTitle description grrDescription application name "SkypeAnswer"
            end tell
        end if
    end growlNotify
end using terms from
```

Reference: [1](http://brettterpstra.com/answer-skype-with-a-hotkey/)

Kind Regards

BHM